# What's the English equivalent of ブタ in poker?

Tags: translation

According to [this site](http://ww6.tiki.ne.jp/~tamatsuo/poker.htm), buta appears to be the colloquial name of a "no pair". Is there such thing as a "no pair"? If not, what is it called in English?

Comment: I think this question is about English rather than Japanese. Try ell or english.stackexchange.com?

Comment: @Yosh I wouldn't go there to ask the meaning of a Japanese word.

Comment: It turns out that I totally misread your intention.  My apologies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [List of poker hands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_poker_hands), ノーペア is called "High Card" or "No Pair" in English.

Note that you may see some 和製英語 terms in poker and other Western-origin games. "Three of a kind" and "Four of a kind" are usually referred to as スリーカード and フォーカード, respectively, in Japanese. (Perhaps "-of-a-kind" was grammatically too difficult for Japanese people.)